# File modification times not equal after calling shutil.copystat(file1, file2) under Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, filesystems

I run the following code with Python 2.7.5. under Windows:

```
import os, shutil, stat, time

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f: pass # create an arbitrary file
shutil.copy('test.txt', 'test2.txt') # copy it
shutil.copystat('test.txt', 'test2.txt') # copy its stats, too

t1 = os.lstat('test.txt').st_mtime # get the time of last modification for both files
t2 = os.lstat('test2.txt').st_mtime

print t1 # prints something like: 1371123658.54
print t2 # prints the same string, as expected: 1371123658.54
print t1 == t2 # prints False! Why?!
```

I expect both timestamps (=floats) to be equal (as their string representations suggest), so why does `t1 == t2` evaluate to `False`?

Also, I was unable to reproduce this behaviour with less code, i.e. without comparing the timestamps retrieved via `os.lstat` from two *different* files. I have the feeling, I am missing something trivial here...

---

***Edit:*** After further testing I noticed, that it does print `True` once in  a while, but not more often than once every 10 runs.

---

***Edit 2:*** As suggested by larsmans:

```
print ("%.7f" % t1) # prints e.g. 1371126279.1365688
print ("%.7f" % t2) # prints e.g. 1371126279.1365681
```

This raises two new questions:

1. Why are the timestamps not equal after calling `shutil.copystat`?
2. `print` rounds floats by default?!

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Debian Linux. Try `print("%.7f" % t1)` and `(t1 - t2) < 1e-4` to see if the "small print" is different.

Comment: To see why print rounds floats by default, try this: `x=10.1 (newline) print ("%.20f" % x)`. This will print something other than you think. This is normal because floating point values cannot represent all fractional values exactly. I have no idea about the shutil problem though.

Comment: I know about binary representation, but here the case is different: We have a float with value `10.099999` and it prints `10.1` although we did not specify a format such as `%.2f` - so there appears to be an implicit rounding in effect, that I did not know about and that I never observed before...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is with conversion between different formats during the `copystat` call. This is because Windows stores file times in a fixed-point decimal format, while Python stores them in a floating-point binary format. So each time there is a conversion between the two formats, some accuracy is lost. During the `copystat` call:

1. A call to `os.stat` converts the Windows format to Python's floating-point format. Some accuracy is lost.
2. `os.utime` is called to update the file time. this converts it back to the Windows format. Some accuracy is lost again, and the file time is not necessarily the same as the first file's.

When you call `os.lstat` yourself, a third inaccurate conversion is performed. Due to these conversions, the file times are not exactly the same.

The [documentation for `os.utime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.utime) mentions this:

> Note that the exact times you set here may not be returned by a subsequent stat() call, depending on the resolution with which your operating system records access and modification times

---

Regarding your second question (why `print` appears to show the same values for both): Converting a floating-point value to a string with `str(f)` or `print f` will round the value. To get a value guaranteed to be unique for different floating-point values, use `print repr(f)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
from decimal import *
print Decimal(t1)
print Decimal(t2)
```

Use round() for t1 and t2

Answer (score -1):

Try printing the time difference in floating point : `print float.hex( t1 - t2)`

results:

```
0x1.0000000000000p-22
0x1.8000000000000p-21
0x0.0p+0
0x1.0000000000000p-20
```

My 2cents guess : the variation in the output comes from floating point representation bias and rounding error. Anyway, you should always use an epsilon values when comparing two float.

EDIT : check this [Python bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue10148) .

> This is a system limitation. The underlying file system supports
>   nanosecond resolution for the file stamps, and stat(2) also supports
>   reporting them. However, utimes(2) only supports microsecond
>   resolution when setting them.

You have to use microsecond resolution at best when comparing the two floats.

Comment: yep, what's more troubling is that t1 is greater than t2, whereas it should the contrary (text2 is more recent than text1)

Comment: That bug report is for a Linux system. The Windows implementation of Python does not use `utimes`, so there is no such microsecond limitation.

Comment: GetFileTime(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724320(v=vs.85).aspx) has a 10 milisecond resolution, so I assume shutil on Windows cannot do better. (I've looked in Python code and lstat call the winapi GetFileAttributesExW
 )

Comment: Again, you are overlooking information in the link. The 10-millisecond resolution is for creation time on FAT filesystem only. NTFS has higher resolution. But it doesn't matter what the resolution is: the inaccuracy is due to conversion to/from floating-point. If the Python implementation had copied the Windows times directly without conversion, the two times would be the same, regardless of the filesystem's resolution.